# How to show an image in a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an image following the ternary operator.

It should be something like

```
<td>${(match(['Completed'] === true && item['Biased'] === item['Hope']) ? 'a.svg' : (item['Completed'] === false && item['Biased'] === null) ? 'b.svg' : 'c.svg')}</td>
```

How do I go about doing this?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the ternary operator is good, but how are you writing js in your html?

Comment: You're missing the markup to create an image tag `<img src="...">` and you're missing the `item` at `item['Completed'] === true`

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald ` var tr = `<tr> ....... </tr>` ` this is how I am doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
<td>${(match(['Completed'] === true && item['Biased'] === item['Hope']) ? '<img src="a.svg" />' : (item['Completed'] === false && item['Biased'] === null) ? '<img src="b.svg" />' : '<img src="c.svg" />')}</td>
```

Updated Answer with `classname`

```
<td>${(match(['Completed'] === true && item['Biased'] === item['Hope']) ? '<img src="a.svg" class="image-1" />' : (item['Completed'] === false && item['Biased'] === null) ? '<img src="b.svg" class="image-2" />' : '<img src="c.svg" class="image-3" />')}</td>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much !! But there is one tiny problem. The image sizes are differing. Can css be added to this?

Comment: @SteveDoson You can add class to each image tag & in the `CSS` you can define the width.

Comment: That's what I did now. Thank you so much mate.